# Target a label whos ID is structured as "lblx1" by doing lblx + variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, while-loop

I have a few labels on my site, which i need to populate with specific values from a database. So I've used a naming convention such as "lblx1", "lblx2", "lblx3" etc. and planned to do the following in a while loop:

```
lblx + id.Text = dbVariable
```

but this can't work as the code needs the name of an existing label in full.

```
    public void beanList()
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,Price250g,Price1kg FROM Beans", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string id = reader["id"].ToString();
            string price250g = reader["Price250g"].ToString();
            string price1kg = reader["Price1kg"].ToString();

            lbl250 + id.Text = price250g;
            lbl1 + id.Text = price1kg;
        }
    }
```

I have also attempted from an anwser:

```
    public void beanList()
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,Price250g,Price1kg FROM Beans", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string id = reader["id"].ToString();
            string price250g = reader["Price250g"].ToString();
            string price1kg = reader["Price1kg"].ToString();

            Label l250g = new Label();
            l250g.ID = "lbl250" + id;
            l250g.Text = price250g;

            Label l1kg = new Label();
            l1kg.ID = "lbl1" + id;
            l1kg.Text = price1kg;
        }
    }
```

But this does nothing, when stepping through "l250g.ID" is set, but "l250g.Text" doesn't work. It runs but is setting the text of the label whos ID it has been given.

Is there a way to get this to work without having to do a separate database query for each label, as the attempted while loop method is ideal as it would be fastest instead of calling the query X amount of times.

Comment: put it in a for loop and use the indexer with the label name...like so lblx[indexer].text = dbVariable

Comment: @GrantWinney I've added the full code of what I'm doing

Comment: @GrantWinney but the code is setting the text of a label which already exists and persists after the loop, as its ID is set to it. Eitherway, placing the creation of the new label outside of the loop still has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List<string, Label>`, like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Label>> elements = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Label>>();
```

Whenever you add an element, you do this:

```
elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, label>("lblx" + ids.Count, myLabel));
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to find the control first. Hope the below code hint helps

```
        string[] id = new string(1); 
        id[0] = reader["id"].ToString();
        string price250g = reader["Price250g"].ToString();
        string price1kg = reader["Price1kg"].ToString();
        string templabel = null; 
        foreach (string i in id)
        {
            templabel = lbx + i;
            var matches = this.Controls.Find(templabel, true).GetValue(0);
            ((Label)matches).Text = price250g;
        }
```

I have specified GetValue(0) for my test. You can take a counter in your case.